# Use jQuery to generate Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I'm trying to generate a Thyemeleaf from Json response:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/getJson',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        var htmlTag = "<span th:text='" + obj.name +
          "'></span>";
        $("#result").append(htmlTag);
      });
    }
  });
```

But it doesn't render. Is it possible to generate html this way?

Comment: It should work, does you `ajax` call work? I mean do you see the call in the network tab with success and everything?

Comment: Also you could use `$.getJSON()` for JSON responses instead of `ajax` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Not sure if th:text dialect will work since it has to compile. Can you instead try var htmlTag = "<span> '" + obj.name +
          "'</span>";